# Seriously, why doesn't my sql get executed '--

Tags: php, sql, apache-flex

I have a flex application which I try to use for inserting data into my database. I'm fully sure that my data reaches my php file and all the variables for my query are inserted on the right place in my query.

BUT: Nothing gets inputted in my database, been searching for hours now, both in flex and php but I cant find the mistake:

```
<?php
include_once("Connection.php");

$go = true;

if(isset($_GET['table'])){
    $tableNr = $_GET['table'];
} else {
    $go = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['gerechtId'])){
    $gerechtID = $_GET['gerechtId'];
} else {
    $go = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['aantal'])){
    $aantal = $_GET['aantal'];
} else {
    $go = false;
}

if($go){
$query = "INSERT INTO bestelling (Tafelnummer, StatusID)
          VALUES (". $tableNr . ", 1);

          INSERT INTO orders (bestellingID, gerechtID, aantal)
          VALUES (@@IDENTITY, " . $gerechtID . ", " . $aantal . ");";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
echo($query);
}
?>
```

I'm quite sure there is no mistake in it, but just to be certain, does my query get executed?

Comment: MySQL by default has 1 statement per query. So you would have to execute each statement in an individual query. (assuming you have not changed the setting)

Comment: Also, fix your SQL injection vulnerability. You need to filter post/get/cookie vars before using them in a query.

Comment: Also, note that the old PHP mysql API that you're using [has been deprecated since PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and will be removed in the future. The newer [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) API _does_ support multiple statements per query.

Comment: Have you used a packet sniffer--such as ServiceCapture or the Flash Builder Network Monitor to make sure that your Flash App is making calls to your PHP Script?

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is also something from MS SQL Server, not MySQL.  Where in the world did you pick that up, and why did you think it might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously, you're not even checking for errors. Do that first, then you'll seriously know:

```
mysql_query($query) or die('Serious error: '.mysql_error());
```

Seriously, you can't execute more than one command per query. At least not in MySQL.

Also, you should seriously stop using mysql_*. It's seriously old and deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi. Here is a nice serious tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers